# Remove duplicate rows of a CSV file based on a single column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates

I have a CSV file that has one column which acts as a serial number. For various reasons that serial number can be repeated on rows, but I want anything other than the most recent listing of that serial number removed.

I imagine this is possible with python/pandas as I currently have it removing if the entire row is a duplicate using pandas. That "almost" works for my needs, but would be much better if I could match only on the one column with the serial number.

Currently it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('c:/LOG/NEWlog.csv')
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.to_csv('c:/PDWLOG/NONDUPES.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='serial column', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Ahh I see now in the pandas documentation that option - thank you! I'll give it a try tomorrow.